# How can I use serde to serialize a struct to another Rust data structure?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a data structure `Document`, which I would like to serialize other Rust structs to. It is basically a `HashMap` for the fields internally, however it interacts with a database API, so I will definitely want to convert other types into those `Document`s.

For example this struct

```
struct Entry {
    id: String,
    user: String,
    duration: u32,
    location: (f64, f64),
}
```

I already have a conversion to the `Document` type using the `From` trait, however this is an extra place I have to modify when the `Entry` struct changes. The implementation uses a `DocumentBuilder` and looks like this:

```
impl From<Entry> for Document {
    fn from(entry: Entry) -> Self {
        Document::builder()
            .name(&entry.id)           // set the name of the document
            .field("user", entry.user) // add fields ...
            .field("duration", entry.duration)
            .field("location", entry.location)
            .build()                   // build a Document

    }
}
```

The `field` method can assign any value which can be converted to a `FieldValue` to a key. So the signature of `field` is:

```
impl DocumentBuilder {
    // ...
    pub fn field<T: Into<FieldValue>>(mut self, key: &str, value: T) -> Self { ... }
    // ...
}
```

I would like to use serde and its derive feature to automatically serialize the struct and its fields into a `Document`. How would I go about doing this? I looked at the wiki for [Implementing a Serializer](https://serde.rs/impl-serializer.html) but the example shown writes to a string and I would like to know how I can serialize to a data structure using the builder pattern.

Comment: I *swear* this has been asked before; I'm positive I misread that question and suggested [serde-transcode](https://serde.rs/transcode.html) before understanding the goal. I believe my suggestion there was just to use `From`, as you have.

Comment: Coming back to this question, today I think writing a proc macro to do this would be much simpler. Simply generate the From implementation automatically, using the builder pattern with the struct field names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use [`serde_json::from_value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_value.html) (applicable even if you're not using JSON, but requires all fields to be valid JSON [e.g. no non-string keys in hashmaps]):

```rust
let entry = Entry {
    a: 24,
    b: 42,
    c: "nice".to_string()
};
let v = serde_json::to_value(&entry).unwrap();
let document: Document = serde_json::from_value(v).unwrap();
```

Caveat: the value type of `Document` will have to implement `Deserialize`, and in a way that can deserialize any value into the correct argument. This can be done by using `#[serde(untagged)]`, but may be prone to certain types being wrong, such as `u8` being converted to `u64`.

[Full playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b1b7fc40161b3785627bd50ea90b788d)

A more sophisticated method that doesn't involve any unnecessary copies will require you to write a custom (De)serializer, and a good one to look at would be [`serde_transcode::transcode`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_transcode/fn.transcode.html), which does the inverse of the thing you want - it converts between two data formats.

Comment: PS: the `Entry` type need implement `serde::ser::Serialize`