# How to remove a struct's field?

Tags: rust

I make a request to a CouchDB database and get a response. Here's the struct for it:

```rust
use couch_rs::{types::{document::DocumentId}, CouchDocument, error::CouchResult};
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, CouchDocument, Default, Debug)]
pub struct GuildEntry {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "String::is_empty")]
    pub _id: DocumentId,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "String::is_empty")]
    pub _rev: String,

    pub embedColor: String
}
```

I want to remove `_id` and `_rev` fields, or at least create a struct instance with all of the fields, except for those two. I can't afford creating a new struct without those fields and transform it from the response, because there's going to be a lot of fields in the future.

**What have I tried/looked into so far:**

- I've looked into [utilizing conversion to serde_json Value and then back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477967/how-can-i-use-serde-to-serialize-a-struct-to-another-rust-data-structure), but I'll need to declare 2 identical structs, but with one has 2 fields missing.
- I've also seen people [mentioning composition](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnrust/comments/o1vd9v/extending_struct_with_another/), but it's kinda ugly and I'd like to avoid using it.
- I can't use `Option` because `CouchDocument` requires that `_id` and `_rev` must be `String` and not `Option<String>`.

How can I accomplish this? Is this even possible?

Comment: You can't omit fields when instantiating a struct. You either need a separate struct or make those fields `Option`s and set their value to `None`.

Comment: @Herohtar Hm, let me try it, gimme a minute

Comment: @Herohtar I can't use `Option` because `CouchDocument` requires that `_id` and `_rev` must be `String` and not `Option<String>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composition is really the only way. Though you don't have to make two separate structures for each; you can use one generic structure:

```
extern crate serde;

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct WithID<T> {
    id: String,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    inner: T,
}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    bar: String,
    baz: String,
}

type FooWithId = WithID<Foo>;
```

Implementing `Deref` and `DerefMut` for `WithID` with `Target = T` would make things easier, as you won't have to reference `inner` as much.

Comment: I really like the `#[serde(flatten)]` macro. Composition still remains, but when I serialize into a JSON string, `inner` "flattens" into the object, just what I need. And implementing `Deref` and `DerefMut` was easier that I thought, thanks!